# How to update BackContent in Mango live tile schedule?

Tags: windows-phone-7, live-tile

I have seen here: [Can I update a live tile in Mango using local data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027812/can-i-update-a-live-tile-in-mango-using-local-data/8030904#8030904)  how to update live tile locally.

Now, I've set

```
var newData = new StandardTileData()
{
    Title = "BrTime "+dt.Hour+":"+dt.Minute+":"+dt.Second,
    BackgroundImage = new Uri("background.png", UriKind.Relative),
             
    BackContent = "Time "+dt.Hour+":"+dt.Minute+":"+dt.Second,
    BackTitle = "The Back",
    BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("background.png", UriKind.Relative)
};
```

Now I would need to update the `BackContent` property of the tile when the scheduler updates the tile. How can I do it? It still remains the time of tile creation.

Answer (score 1):

Cris,

How are you updating your tiles? If using ShellTileSchedule, only the Background Image of the front of tile may be updated. See this post: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769548(VS.92).aspx.

Not the solution, but hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand you're trying to do, I'll show the code you use for one of my apps on your tile.

```
private void updateTile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            // get application tile
            ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.First();
            if (null != tile)
            {
                // create a new data for tile
                StandardTileData data = new StandardTileData();
                // tile foreground data
                data.Title = "Estilo Nokia";
                data.BackgroundImage = new Uri("Background.png", UriKind.Relative);
                // to make tile flip add data to background also
                data.BackTitle = "Estilo Nokia";
                data.BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("Backback.png", UriKind.Relative);
                data.BackContent = "¡Nuevas Noticias!";
                // update tile
                tile.Update(data);
                }
```

In the opening of the constructor add

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        updateTile_Click(null, null);
```